# Isolation of a power lane (for industrial digital input card)

Tags: power, digital-logic, isolation, industry

I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve some data from sensors in an industrial environment. For this we have a carrier board that is powered with 24V and generates 5 and 3.3 voltages to power up all the logic. Attached to this carrier would fit the IOmodules, which will get the 24V and 3.3V power lanes. The 3.3V voltage will be used to power the uC of the IOmodule, and the 24V is intended for only industrial purposes. For the input of the sensors, I decided to go with MAX22190 IC, and going through the datasheet I found out that there's a way of providing isolation through the SPI comms to protect the uC. The topology of the circuit would be the following one:

[image: Topology of the input from the sensors taken from the datasheet]

in my case I don't have a 2.5V supply but a 3.3V oneAs you can see in this image, a 24V voltage is feed to the MAX22190, the 3.3V is generated by it's internal LDO to feed the Vl and the MAX14483 B side (the A side would be connected to the uC).

This topology makes much sense if the 24V source it's taken from the same power source that powers the sensors, but in my case it would be taken from my own board. This brings some problematic: The grounds from each side are isolated. If I bring my 24V (from lets call it A side) to power up the MAX22190 (B side), I cannot be sure that those will be actually 24V since the grounds are isolated, so to make sure it is 24V I should attach those 2 grounds, thus breaking somehow the isolation. From here I thought about 2 solutions.

1. Isolate the 24V lane and the ground lane through something like a 1:1 transformer. The problem is that I haven't been able to find any device that could do this work. It is actually possible to accomplish this?
2. As I said before, just connect the 2 grounds, maybe not worry too much about the isolation and just place some TVS diodes and schottky diodes for ESD protection in the 24V lane? And maybe isolate the 24V ground from the 3.3V and 5V through an LC filter, like a capacitor and a ferrite beads? (the 24V source will power all the board as I said before, and from there create the other voltage. This way I would have grounds connected at 0Hz frequency, but current or voltage spikes could be suppressed, idk).

It feels having isolation in every other lane except the power supply lane (24V) is kinda troll (don't get me wrong, ofc some isolation is better than none) and it scares me that a failure in the input could end up damaging the rest of the electronics (as I said before, only 3.3V and 5V are used to power electronics, 24V are only to generate those voltages and to be used on the industrial stuff (digital inputs, outputs...)).

Any help/advice in this matter would be very appreciated, and I don't mind changing my design/starting from scratch again, so if you have a better approach/ideas don't hesitate on telling.

Thank you!

"Block diagram" of the  module and design.[image]

(in my case I don't have a 2.5V supply but a 3.3V one)

Comment: Please draw a block diagram showing where you think you need to provide isolation.

Comment: @Andyaka I edited the post to add the "block diagram". Sorry for the drawing, not my best feature. Anyway, in the picture you can see that 24V lane that comes from the CARRIER connector. Every other signal is isolated from the uC, but the 24V one. I don't know if this helped with your understanding.

Comment: Have you looked at isolating dc to dc converters from murata and recom?

Comment: Yeah, I'll be actually using those to convert from 24V to 5V and 3.3V. The 24V are given to me, that would be my supply for my whole board, so it's not like I'm thinking on converting 24/24V (although if you tell me it could be a good way, I'll take a look).

Anyhow, that's why I said about isolating the ground for 3.3V and 5V and connecting it to the 24V ground through an LC filter, although I don't know if this would be a good practise.